# mysqli multi query separation

Tags: php, mysqli

I know you can run multiple queries with `mysqli_multi_query` but I have a problem :

For a registration page I want to perform 2 checks and then an insert :

- Check1 = Does username exist?
- Check2 = Email already been used?
- **If both checks are negative** then do the insert query.

But how can I sepperate the errors ?

- when a username exists it has to return '**Username already exists**'
- if email is already been used it has to return '**Email already in use**'

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "check username query; ";
$sql .= "check email query; ";
$sql .= "Insert query";

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql)) {
    do
    {
        if ($result=mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    //DO STUFF
                    //Here do i need to return if the username or email exists or not.
            };
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        };
    } else {
        echo 'Query fout!';
    };
        while (mysqli_next_result($con));
};

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Why combine the statements and then struggle to work out where the problems are.  Running individual statements (if necessary) or coding 1 SQL to do various checks would be easier to work out where the problems are.

Comment: If you really want to, you could use one query for the check, like `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?) AS name_exists,EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?) AS email_exists`, but I would still put the INSERT in another query. Or you could make those columns unique, and check for uniqueness violation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You do not write a `;` after an `if` statement or a loop. Furthermore, your `do {} while();` loop is not in the correct format.

Correct Format:

```
$sql = "check username query; ";
$sql .= "check email query; ";
$sql .= "Insert query";

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql)) {
    do {
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    //DO STUFF
                    //return if the username or email exists
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo 'Query fout!';
        } 
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: hi, this wasn't the problem. The problem is that i need to check whether a username and / or email address exists and if not, it does an insert.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_multi_query()` is not the tool to use for this.

That mysql[i] requires you to jump through hoops to execute more than one DML operation per call provides a lot of protection against sql injection (but it still falls a long way of a full solution for such attacks). There is no need to implement these as a multi-statement-query.

There is a performance and scalability benefit to limiting the number of round trips to the database - but you can do this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF('$username'=user.username, 1, 0)) AS usernames,
   SUM(IF('$email'=user.email, 1, 0)) as emails
FROM users
WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'
```

to get the results in a single query.

It would be even more efficient to not bother with a SELECT, but instead add a unique index to each of the attributes in the database then handle a duplicate record error if the INSERT fails although this does not make for such a nice user experience. OTOH it does prevent enumeration attacks against the database.

Comment: i found another solution for this,  i check with AJAX. Each Ajax call can run a sepperate sql query

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that coming, an even more inefficient and slightly more insecure solution than where you started from!